# How to convert XML to Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have below XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Revisions>
        <Revision name="R1">
            <MasterTags>
                <MasterTag name="MT1">
                    <ChildTags>
                        <ChildTag>CT1</ChildTag>
                    </ChildTags>
                </MasterTag>
                <MasterTag name="MT2">
                    <ChildTags>
                        <ChildTag>CT4</ChildTag>
                    </ChildTags>
                </MasterTag>
        </Revision>
        <Revision name="R2">
            <MasterTags>
                <MasterTag name="MT6">
                    <ChildTags>
                        <ChildTag>CT21</ChildTag>
                        <ChildTag>CT22</ChildTag>
                        <ChildTag>CT23</ChildTag>   
                    </ChildTags>
                    </MasterTag>
                <MasterTag name="MT7">
                    <ChildTags>
                        <ChildTag>CT24</ChildTag>
                        <ChildTag>CT25</ChildTag>
                        <ChildTag>CT26</ChildTag>   
                    </ChildTags>
                </MasterTag>
         </Revision>
   </Revisions>
```

I want to convert this XML into Dictionary of Dictionaries using LINQ

```
Dim dicRevisionTags As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)))
```

I tried using

```
 Dim document = XDocument.Load("Inputxml.xml")
```

also something like

```
Dim ccc = document.Elements("Revisions").ToDictionary(Function(e) e.Elements("Revision").ToDictionary(Function(d) d.Elements("MasterTags")))
```

but unable to construct LINQ that give output as

```
R1-> key, Value( M1, list(of CT1))
        , Value( M2, list(of CT4))

R2-> key, Value( M6, list(of CT21
                             CT22
                             CT23))
        , Value( M7, list(of CT24
                             CT25
                             CT26))
```

Thanks
Gurpreet Gill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
var result = 
    doc.Root
       .Elements("Revision")
       .ToDictionary(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                     x => x.Element("MasterTags")
                           .Elements("MasterTag")
                           .ToDictionary(y => (string)y.Attribute("name"),
                                         y => y.Element("ChildTags")
                                               .Elements("ChildTag")
                                               .Select(z => (string)z)
                                               .ToList()));
```

It is C#, but you should be able to translate it.

Comment: VB Version :: 


Dim ldicRevisionTags As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))) =
            document.Root.Elements("Revision").ToDictionary(Function(x) CType(x.Attribute("name"), String),
                                                            Function(x) x.Element("MasterTags").Elements("MasterTag").ToDictionary(Function(y) CType(y.Attribute("name"), String),
                                                            Function(y) y.Element("ChildTags").Elements("ChildTag").[Select](Function(z) z.Value).ToList()))